# NCO: is there any one-line command to change the index of time dimension as a whole array (not by for-loop)?

Tags: datetime, netcdf, netcdf4, nco, timestep

I have a netCDF file `FORCING.nc` containing dimension "time" with values like: `[ 841512.,  841513.,  841514., ..., 1051893., 1051894.,1051895.]`. But I want to change the time stamps from the absolute value to relative values starting from 841512, say change it to `[0, 1, 2,...,1051895-841512]=[0, 1, 2,...,210383]`. So is there any one-line `nco` command to do it?
Thanks a lot!

Some code example but in python (sorry I am not familiar with nco...):

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
file_small = Dataset('./FORCING.nc')
file_small['time'][:]
```

Then I can get output like:

```
Out[5]: 
masked_array(data=[ 841512.,  841513.,  841514., ..., 1051893., 1051894.,
                   1051895.],
             mask=False,
       fill_value=1e+20,
            dtype=float32)
```

What I want to do, is change the value of `time` from `[ 841512.,  841513.,  841514., ..., 1051893., 1051894.,1051895.]` to `[0, 1, 2,...,1051895-841512]=[0, 1, 2,...,210383]`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the ncap2 documentation [here](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncap2).

```
ncap2 -s 'time-=841512' in.nc out.nc
```

Comment: Thanks! but I am afraid it makes more sense (and more flexible) to use ```ncap2 -O -s 'time=time-time(0)' FORCING.nc FORCING.nc```.